# This Code will not copy the contents of One ADODB to another ADODB & I can't figure out why

Tags: database, vb6, adodb

This is pure VB6 SP3 - 8169 (Professional)
Windows 8.1
Version 6.3.9600
Toshiba Satellite S75t-A
Intel Core i7-4700MQ

Running the code throws the error shown in the uploaded dialogue.[image]

---

```
Public Sub DBTrans()
    Dim OldNum As Integer, NewNum As Integer
    Dim New_CDBS, New_WRS, Old_CDBS, Old_WRS
    Dim Resp, Rec As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim Txt0, Txt1, Txt2, Txt3, Txt5, Txt6
    
    
    ' Open the Database you are getting records 'FROM'
    Set Old_CDBS = OpenDatabase(SourceDB, True)
    Set Old_WRS = Old_CDBS.OpenRecordset("Passwords", dbOpenDynaset)
    
    ' Open the DataBase you are sending Records 'TO'
    Set New_CDBS = OpenDatabase(DestinationDB, True)
    Set New_WRS = CDBS.OpenRecordset("Passwords", dbOpenDynaset)
    
    On Error GoTo ErrRes
    
    Old_WRS.MoveFirst   ' Initialize Source Database
    Old_WRS.MoveLast
    Old_WRS.MoveFirst
    i = 1
    
    Do Until Old_WRS.EOF = True     'Cycle through all Records in the Source Database in this 'DO' Loop
        With New_WRS
         ' This was a test workaround effort
         '   Txt0 = Old_WRS.Fields(0)
         '   Txt1 = Old_WRS.Fields(1)
         '   Txt2 = Old_WRS.Fields(2)
         '   Txt3 = Old_WRS.Fields(3)
         '   Txt4 = Old_WRS.Fields(4)       ' OR Rec_Num OR i
         '   Txt5 = Old_WRS.Fields(5)
         '   Txt6 = Old_WRS.Fields(6)
        
            .AddNew     ' Add A new Record to the Destination Database
            .Fields(0).Value = Old_WRS.Fields(0)        '= Txt0   ' Location
            .Fields(1).Value = Old_WRS.Fields(1)        '= Txt1   ' Logon
            .Fields(2).Value = Old_WRS.Fields(2)        '= Txt2   ' Password
            .Fields(3).Value = Old_WRS.Fields(3)        '= Txt3   ' Notes - AllowZeroLength Field
            .Fields(5).Value = Old_WRS.Fields(5)        '= Txt5   ' Format(Txt5, "mm/dd/yyyy")
            .Fields(6).Value = Old_WRS.Fields(6)        '= Txt6   ' Name
            
            .Fields(4).Value = Old_WRS.Fields(4)        ' New_Index 'OR' Rec_Num
           
          '  i = i + 1      ' Next index OR Rec_Num
            .Update
            .MoveFirst
            .MoveLast
                        
        End With
        Old_WRS.MoveNext        ' Move to next Source Database Record
        
    Loop                    ' Start Next data Transaction.
    
    ' Old_WRS.RecordCount is complete
    ' now Verify transfer with simple RecordSet.Count comparison
    OldNum = Old_WRS.RecordCount
    NewNum = New_WRS.RecordCount
    Old_WRS.Close
    Old_CDBS.Close
    New_WRS.Close
    Old_CDBS.Close
    
    
    If NewNum = OldNum Then
        MsgBox ("Transfer complete: Old DB = " & OldNum & "Records" & vbCr & "New DB has " & NewNum & "Records."), vbOKOnly
    Else
        MsgBox ("Something went wrong: Old DB = " & OldNum & "Records" & vbCr & "New DB has " & NewNum & " Records."), vbOKOnly
    End If

ErrRes:

    MsgBox "The Following Error Occurred:" & vbCr & vbCr & Err.Description & vbCr & "Aborting Edit Operation", vbOKOnly, "Error Alert"
    Form1.Visible = True
    Form1.Enabled = True
    Unload Form4

End Sub
```

Comment: Which line throws the error?

Comment: So, following the text of the error message, do you have any indexes, primary keys, or relationships on the table?  It says you're duplicating one of those.  Doesn't look like a problem inherently with the code (although it does look like it will print the error message 100% of the time), but rather, it looks like a problem with the data youre trying to insert into the DB.

Comment: New_WRS.Update - Everytime.  The DB is updateable.  I tried loading the data elements into String variables and then dump them to the DB.

Comment: I tried loading the data elements into String variables and then dump them to the DB.  All I did when I created the DB was to make increase the size of the 'Location' field from 50 to 250, the 'Name' field from 50 to 150.  This was to accommodate the larger strings common to URL's now-a-days.  I tried it with and without an index.  I tried it with every field zero length (empty) allowed (there are none except for the 'Memo'

Comment: field)... Hmmm could it be trying to copy an empty Memo field into an empty Memo field?  Seems like that would throw an error on the spot.  Every field is a 'String' or text field except the Rec_Num.  I ran the entire copy process with the 'Update' cmd outside the Loop and it copied every data element, all 156 records without a hitch and then executed the Update after leaving the loop, with a direct call to the dynaset.  Could it be because the original DB was 2.0 and the new one is 7.0?

Comment: Oh, and yeah, as submitted the ErrRes would fire every time a mistake on my part when cleaning up the code to paste here.

Comment: Try removing `.Fields(Xxx).Value = Old_WRS.Fields(Xxx)` lines one by one until it succeeds. Note that you are calling `Old_CDBS.Close` twice after the loop and second call will always fail so fix it by removing all the lines calling `Close` on conn/recordset -- you don't need these to be explicit.